# WinAPI Get access to another application's controls

Tags: c++, winapi, dll-injection

I need to get list of all controls from win calculator (calc.exe) and press buttons on calc from my application. 
I tried code injection and now could execute my code from calc application. In the example it sends msg box:

```
#define PROC_NAME _T("calc.exe")
#define MAX_READ 128
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

#pragma comment(linker,"/BASE:0x13140000") 

//-------- My code, which will be executed  from the app-------

DWORD WINAPI func(LPVOID)
{
    LoadLibrary(_T("kernel32.dll")); 
    LoadLibrary(_T("user32.dll"));
    MessageBox(0,_T("Hello from addres area of calculator"),_T("title"),0);
    return true;
}

//-------- find process ---------

DWORD GetProcessID(LPCWSTR lpNameProcess) 
{
    HANDLE snap;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pentry32;
    snap=CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);
    if(snap==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return 0;
    pentry32.dwSize=sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if(!Process32First(snap,&pentry32)) {CloseHandle(snap);return 0;}
    do
    {
        if(!lstrcmpi(lpNameProcess,&pentry32.szExeFile[0]))
        {
            CloseHandle(snap);
            return pentry32.th32ProcessID;
        }
    }
    while(Process32Next(snap,&pentry32));
    CloseHandle(snap);
    return 0;
}

//-------- injection to another process -------------------

BOOL Inject(HANDLE hProc,DWORD(WINAPI* func)(LPVOID))
{
    DWORD id;
    DWORD ByteOfWriten;
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    DWORD size=((PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER)((LPVOID)((BYTE*)(hModule)+((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)(hModule))->e_lfanew+sizeof(DWORD)+sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER))))->SizeOfImage;
    char* hNewModule = (char*)VirtualAllocEx(hProc,hModule,size,MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if(hNewModule==NULL) return false;
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc,hNewModule,hModule,size,&ByteOfWriten);
    if(ByteOfWriten!=size){return false;}
    HANDLE hThread=CreateRemoteThread(hProc,NULL,0,func,(LPVOID)hNewModule,0,&id);
    if(hThread==0) return false;
    return true;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if(!Inject(OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false,GetProcessID(PROC_NAME)),&func)) return false;
}
```

### But how can I make buttons clicks and get text from some controls on calc?

how i tried to enumerate child windows :

```
HWND hwnd, child;
    child = NULL;
    char buf[MAX_STR];          
    hwnd = getMyWnd();  // my own func, returns hwnd to main window 
    do 
    {
        //  here i tried to get child windows
        child = FindWindowExA(hwnd, child, NULL, NULL);
        GetWindowTextA( child, buf, MAX_STR - 1 );
        printf(buf); printf("\n");      
    } while (child != NULL);
```

Comment: Why inject? Why don't you just send the messages direct to the windows since calc is obliging in that regard.

Comment: I just test on calc. I know, that I can get handle of calc and enumerate child windows to get controls. But with another app, for which I made it, I cannot do that. I can only get main window, there aren't child windows.

Comment: how would injection help you in that situation?

Comment: It is not quite that easy, lots of messages require pointers that need to be valid in the target process.  Still, using VirtualAllocEx + Write/ReadProcessMemory is still a lot easier to get going than injecting a DLL.

Comment: And there's no good reason that you can't enumerate child windows once you got the main window.  Code you didn't post, can't guess.

Comment: i added code to the first post how i tried to enumerate child windows.

Comment: @Hans Lots of messages don't need any cross-process marshalling though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already obtained required button handles

If so try this - SendMessage(hButton, BN_CLICKED, 0, 0) I dont remember the constants, you will probably have to look them up.

Update to get button window handles - 
1. Enumerate Child Windows of calculator using EnumChildWindows()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494(VS.85).aspx

1. For each such window find if its a button by inspecting text on it using GetWindowText
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520(VS.85).aspx
2. Make an array of all button handles and click on them like to your hearts content :)

Comment: to do that I need handle on button(hButton). But i don't know how to get it.

Comment: From the `GetWindowText` link: "However, GetWindowText cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application."

Answer (score 1):

Check out MSAA and UIAutomation APIs on MSDN - they are designed to let one application get information about the controls in another, and are often used by automated testing and accessibility tools and apps.

The inspect.exe tool that's part of the Windows SDK uses these; and you should be able to use it to examine and interact with the buttons in calc or various other apps.

All the system controls in Windows support these APIs, as do many other apps (eg. IE, Firefox); but it likely won't work in some 3rd party apps that are just drawing their own UI.