# How can I get the state of media playback using the Win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

When you have music playing and you hit the Media Play/Pause button in Windows (such as on a keyboard with that key) the media control box UI appears in the top left of Windows showing the Title, Artist, Album, etc. of the song you are listening to. How can I get the state of playback (basically if the middle button is a play button or a pause button) using the Win32 API?

[image: Picture of the UI I am referring to.]

I know that there is a way to go about this using UWP and the [`SystemMediaTransportControls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SystemMediaTransportControls?view=winrt-20348) class, but I'd rather not transform my whole application from the Win32 API to UWP just for this functionality.

Comment: MFC programming has been like 20 years ago for me.
But I remember it involves finding the windows handle of the control in the other process.
I used this tool to do that
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019 

This might be a place to start digging deeper too :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235397/winapi-get-access-to-another-applications-controls

Comment: @pep Why did you bring up MFC at all? No one was talking about MFC, at all. And your proposed solution is just all-around useless. I mean, how well does it fare with applications it doesn't know?

Comment: Make sure you understand that the UWP and the Windows Runtime aren't the same thing. The latter can be used from any application regardless of the application model it uses.

Comment: @IInspectable You're right. I jumped to conclussions too soon based on what I knew.

Comment: Is this it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/handling-events-in-c

Comment: @VladFeinstein that is documentation for the Windows Media Player, which is an application for playing music, videos, etc.. It is not the integrated media control system that you can use using the media keys on a keyboard, so that info isn't really useful for the issue I am having. Thank you for the input though.